# How can I stop the Z shell from conspiring to tamper with the output of GNU Make?

Tags: terminal, zsh, make

My research suggests that the [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) has close ties with two secret societies. These ties are revealed when contrasting the output of [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) when using `bash` vs. `zsh`. I would like to know how to configure my shell to foil whatever devious plans have been plotted against me.

1. **Illuminati**

   The object of this partnership seems to be to hide secrets in plain sight. Consider the output of the following simple `Makefile`:

   ```
   test:
       @echo "# header"
       @echo "line with a hash # in the middle"
   ```

   If I run this in my `zsh` shell, the first line is hidden from me. This isn't a problem with escaping the hash because (a) only the first line has a problem, (b) redirecting this to a file makes it show up fine, at which point `cat`ing the file to the same terminal shows up fine, and (c) if I copy from the terminal the text is actually there, it just shows up as black.

   [image: output of makefile in zsh vs bash]

   How can I stop whatever `zsh` is doing to the output that hides secret messages so I can make fully informed decisions based on the output?
2. **Freemasonry**

   The object of this partnership seems to be to release as little information as possible about what's going on behind the scenes. Consider the output of this simple Makefile:

   ```
   test:
       for i in $$(seq 1 10); do echo -n "[$$i]"; sleep 1; done
   ```

   If I run this is in my `zsh` shell, the output is buffered somewhere until a newline is reached or the target is completed. Then and only then is anything given back to the terminal. This makes long running jobs that actually show something while they are working but don't include frequent line breaks in the output very hard to follow. By contrast the output I get from `bash` is much more informative.

   [image: asciicast]

   How can I stop whatever `zsh` is doing that censors the output until forced to reveal it so that I can see what's going on as it happens?

If any of this is relevant, I'm using GNU Make 4.2.1, Z shell 5.2, and running it inside of Tmux 2.4 in a Termite v12 window. My dotfiles are available for [zsh](https://github.com/alerque/que-zsh), [tmux](https://github.com/alerque/que-tmux) and [Termite](https://github.com/alerque/que-xorg/tree/master/.config/termite).

Also note neither of these issues seem to have anything to do with the shell `make` runs internally as adding `SHELL = bash` to the Makefile doesn't change anything.

Comment: Zsh 5.2 doesn't do any of that on my system, which suggests it's something to do with your Zsh configuration, tmux or Termite.

Comment: @StephenKitt That's kind of what I figured, but I tried hacking out bits of configuration and wasn't having much luck identifying the culprit. I linked to my own configs, but I actually saw at least the second issue on somebody else's system that uses the shell so little I'm pretty sure the dotfile situation was bone-stock distro. It would be nice to know and _understand_ what options are affecting this and possibly how to use them to my advantage rather than just figuring out what to disable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## By not using add-ons whose purpose is exactly that.

It's not the Z shell doing this; nor tmux, nor termite.

You have installed an add-on from Prezto (or something similar) whose **documented purpose** is to "tamper with the output of GNU Make".  The top of the add-on reads:

```
#
# Highlights make output.
#
# Authors:
#   Sorin Ionescu <sorin.ionescu@gmail.com>
#
```

As you can see, when you ran

```
make test
```

you weren't running the actual `make` program, but were instead running the add-on named `make` that you installed.  It, in turn, was running a command named `colormake`.

And what does `colormake` do?  It runs `make` with its standard output and standard error not being a terminal device, piping them it into a Perl program that reads and processes its standard input one whole line at a time.  You could actually reproduce all of the effects that you see, *in any POSIX compatible shell*, by doing the same thing:

```
/usr/bin/make test 2>&1 | colormake.pl
```

This is nothing to do with the Z shell and everything to do with the fact that you installed a plug-in that replaced the `make` command.

To witness the line at a time behaviour on its own, without the colourization and detection of comments and so forth that `colormake.pl` does, *in any POSIX compatible shell* run:

```
/usr/bin/make test 2>&1 | perl -e 'while (<>) { print $_ ; }'
```

So deinstall or disable the add-on that you installed.

Prezto replaces the `diff` command, too.

## Further reading

- Bjarni Rúnar Einarsson.  [Colormake](https://github.com/pagekite/Colormake).
- Sorin Ionescu (2012).  [`make`](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/blob/master/modules/utility/functions/make#L2). Prezto.
- Sorin Ionescu (2012).  [`diff`](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/blob/master/modules/utility/functions/diff#L2). Prezto.